# Launch .exe from MATLAB m.file, path issues

Tags: windows, matlab, command-line, exe

I want to Launch and .exe file from an m-file in MATLAB. The .exe does not Launch when i try. In restPath, the path of the .exe included. I am coding in a Windows Environment using the command line. My idea was to pass the command to run the .exe to the command line.

```
command = restPath;
[status,cmdout] = system(command,'-echo');
```

The error message is; Error file .cfg not found...

Do you have any suggestions?
Best regards

Edit: The .exe is now launched in 2 iterations. 1. cd to file, 2. Launch

```
addpath(restPath);
command = horzcat('cd ',restPath);
[status,cmdout] = dos(command,'-echo');

execute = 'abc.exe';
[statusExe,cmdoutExe] = system(execute,'-echo');
```

Comment: what does restPath include? you are running 'restPath' as the command, what is it meant to do? Meaning if you want to run your exe, you should be able to do something like system('"myexe.exe", someParameter')

Comment: restPath is structured like this: path/to/file/myexe.exe. The declaration is a bit confusing. The command meant to Launch the .exe

Comment: If it's format is a String, then we should assume that your call to launch the exe file is correct, does you exe file need any configuration files (which needs to be on the path as well) ?

Comment: Yes, the command is correct since the exe runs with that command in the Windows command line. But in MATLAB this didnt work because the exe-file requires a Directory with the configuration files. As you suggest I guess I have to include that path. How can I do this?

Comment: you can either use `addpath` to add the path of your files to your project, or use this : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html which allows Matlab to access the path of your exe file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue that I see here is that you are using two separate commands for the cd and the execution. Once the cd command executes, the command line context is thrown away and you start with a new one when you execute the system command (so the cd has no effect).

I would suggest either concatenating the two commands into one using the '&' notation like the following:

```
[status,cmdout] = dos([command ' & ' execute],'-echo');
```

or you could change your Matlab workspace first using a standard cd command in your mscript and then execute the system command.

```
currentPath = pwd;
cd(restPath);

execute = 'abc.exe';
[statusExe,cmdoutExe] = system(execute,'-echo');

cd(currentPath);
```

It is also possible that the exe you are calling is expecting an additional input to point to the .cfg file (although this may not be an issue if you have that in the same directory as the exe and it expects it to be there).